# When step am I missing from moving a premade code from Codepen into my Brackets project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the codepen I'm trying to get working: http://codepen.io/Bounasser-Abdelwahab/pen/ruiky

Here is the head of my index.html file in my Brackets project:

```
<head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

When I try to run this, it runs about 90% correctly, but it's not a complete match. The menu is misaligned, and I can see bullet points that weren't there before, and the padding is all wrong.

How can I get a complete replication of the codepen code into my own project?

Edit: here is an image of how mine is coming out: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNglE.png

Edit 2:

Here is my slightly modified HTML. Problem is persisting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--

-->
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    </head>



   <body>

<ul class="navbar cf">
            <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub item 3</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">google</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">yahoo!</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">jQuery</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 2</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">sub sub sub item 1</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">sub sub sub item 2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">sub sub sub item 3</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sub item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sub item 3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                      </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 5</a>

                  </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">item a little longer</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
        </ul>





    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you have jquery added twice ?

Comment: Lol, uhhhhhh, I don't know! 

I changed that now. Sadly, it didn't fix the problem I'm having, but I'm still glad to have made that change haha.

Comment: hope this class u should add: `ol, ul {
    list-style: outside none none;
}`

Comment: I went ahead and edited the original post to include my full HTML. My CSS (style.css) and JS (init.js) are the exact same as the codepen's, nothing else is on them.

Comment: Thank you, I've added that to the style.css page and it fixed a lot of the problems. Here is a screenshot now: http://i.imgur.com/9FIvpnk.png

There is still a strange extra space to the left that shouldn't be there. Do you happen to have suggestions for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the class which will resolve those issues:

```
`ol, ul { list-style: outside none none; }`
```

Answer (score 1):

As you asked, another question later on, so adding another answer.

For removing the strange extra space to the left of some boxes,
Add below CSS class:

```
.body{
    //your other class properties ...
    padding:0
}
```

Comment: I wish I could mark both answers as 'this solved my problem'! It works perfectly now. Thank you very much!!